# Cannot connect to Mysql server in docker from another container

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm sitting now and looking for solution over 6 hours. Please help me. First of all I will try explain my problem. I created MySql database using image (in dcoker), but when I want create another container (Sprig Boot) and connect to the Database I cannot. I tried created only image of MySql and conntect from intellij and everything is correct. Only when I try creat project in container is problem...

My docer-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: ./springboot-api-docker
    ports:
    - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - database
  database:
    container_name: 'localhost'
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: animaldb
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
```

application properties

```
server.port = 9090

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/animaldb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

and DocerFile

```
FROM openjdk:8u201-jdk-alpine3.9
ADD target/springboot-api-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
EXPOSE 9090
CMD java -jar springboot-api-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

It's funny because... first I wantet change  name of container "localhost" to another. But when I was changing that I couldn't run Spring Bot Application even from intellij. I created image of MySql in docker and I was trying to conntect in intellij. It was warking but when I want use SpringBoot Application in caontainer then is problem. I didn't find solve for me yet. I will be very thankful for each help.

My errors here.

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create
>   connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

And all text from console. Maybe you will find it faster.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to
>   create requested service
>   [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] api_1       |   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar!/:5.4.9.Final]
>
> Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure api_1       | api_1       | The last
>   packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The
>   driver has not received any packets from the server. api_1       |
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:91)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:144)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   ... 58
>   common frames omitted api_1       | Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   api_1       |   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_201] api_1       |
>   at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   at
>   com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18] api_1       |   ... 60
>   common frames omitted

Comment: What errors are you getting and what environment (mac/windows/linux) are you running?

Comment: I edited again the post. I can't creat a conneaction with mysql. I use Windows.

Comment: @Andrii have you found the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not good to use localhost as you docker container name.

Change localhost to database like it.

localhost is always your local machine or a local docker, not external resource.

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build: ./springboot-api-docker
    ports:
    - "9090:9090"
    depends_on:
      - database
    links:
      - database
  database:
    container_name: 'database'
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_DATABASE: animaldb
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
```

**application.properties**:

```
server.port = 9090

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database: 3306/animaldb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
```

Comment: I know but It does't work still. The name doesn't cause the error.

Comment: You are using external port 3307, try to use 3306 in spring.datasource.url.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late after 2 years, but you should create network first and add two containers to the network.

```
docker network create network name

docker run yourcontainter --net network name
```

Comment: all the containers that run in a docker-compose file will be in the same network unless you config otherwise